# The PATCH method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: laravel, crud, laravel-form

```
<form action="{{ route('todo.edit',$todoedit->id,'edit') }}" method="POST" class="container">
        @csrf
        @method('PATCH')
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="{{$todoedit->title}}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="{{$todoedit->description}}">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Update</button>
        </form>
```

Todo Controller:

```
    public function edit(Request $request,$id)
    { 
        $todo=Todo::find($id);
        $todo->title=$request->title;
        $todo->description=$request->description;
        $todo->save();
        return redirect(route('todo.index'));
    }
```

I do not know what seems to be the problem, I am doing the CRUD, everything is working but the Update part is not working, it is giving me the error

> The PATCH method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

I have tried everything, `@method('UPDATE')` and `PUT` and everything but it does not work

Comment: please paste your routes code: ```web.php```

Comment: web.php:

Route::resource('todo', 'TodoController');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you write your update function body in edit method in your controller. Do as below:

```
    public function update(Request $request,$id)
    { 
        $todo=Todo::find($id);
        $todo->title=$request->title;
        $todo->description=$request->description;
        $todo->save();
        return redirect(route('todo.index'));
    }
```

and in your edit method just return edit view and pass `$todo` object to that

Method type of edit is: **Get**

Method type of update is: **Put** or **Patch**

You can see this types with simple run `php artisan route:list` in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

In Web.php May Work

```
Route::patch('/todo/edit/{id}', [TodoController::class, 'edit']);
```